# Android AVD “Unfortunately, <app> has stopped.”

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview, android-webview

My application works only once, on the second run (and others...) I've got "Unfortunately, myapp has stopped". I've tried a lot, but there is no effects for me. Here's the code:

MainActivity:
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The activity is about to become visible.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // The activity is about to be destroyed.
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exit:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

WebViewActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;





import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The activity is about to become visible.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // The activity is about to be destroyed.
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
09-05 05:53:27.080: I/Choreographer(815): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 05:53:27.391: D/dalvikvm(815): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 88K, 6% free 2654K/2808K, paused 136ms, total 139ms
09-05 05:53:27.760: I/Choreographer(815): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 05:53:27.771: D/gralloc_goldfish(815): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-05 05:53:27.931: I/Choreographer(815): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-05 05:53:28.630: E/chromium_net(815): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/backend_impl.cc:1107: [0905/055328:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1107)] Critical error found -8
09-05 05:53:28.641: W/chromium_net(815): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0905/055328:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
09-05 05:53:28.651: D/chromium(815): Unknown chromium error: -401
09-05 05:53:28.670: W/chromium_net(815): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/storage_block-inl.h:119: [0905/055328:WARNING:storage_block-inl.h(119)] Failed data load.
09-05 05:53:29.210: E/cutils-trace(815): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-05 05:53:29.271: D/TilesManager(815): Starting TG #0, 0x2a2a6710
09-05 05:53:58.921: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(815): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-05 05:54:00.280: I/Choreographer(815): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues in your logcat. First you get a strange, critical error -8 in combination with accessing the disk cache in the emulator. Second, your main thread does too much work.

For the disk problem: There're many possible reasons. Your Host disk might be full, broken or such. Check your Pc and recreate the virtual device with a new disk. If the issue causes slow IO on the disk, your second problem might go away immediately.

For the main thread work. The only thing in your code that does anything is the `loadUrl()`. If you're loading a large web page and/or use slot JavaScript on the page it can be a pot work and cause the WebView to freeze. Do the loading in another thread.

Comment: It helped, but now I've got problems with entering the menu. I need to press BACK button first, then site dissapears and after this, when i press MENU button it actually works... Is it the problem with threading?

Comment: @Slawek Lech. It works means you've put the code in an extra thread or you checked your disk? Back an menu button forces the page to be redrawn. So it looks like the page gets loaded in the background and not refreshed when done.

Comment: I've put the code in an extra thread. But since I've been suspecting problems with my disk, I also recreated virtual device.

Comment: Do you get the same error messages or different ones? If different consider editing this question or ask a new one with the new problem. You will get a larger audience then just me :-)

Comment: Well, you might be right. I will ask another question. Thank you for help and your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You should call the super before you perform any other operation. Still I do not understand the need to assign this to a final Context object

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why final Context context?? You can just start activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Context context = this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.myfirstapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.WebViewActivity" />
 </application>

</manifest>
```

this should be your manifest file.Check this

Comment: It looks exactly like this

Comment: send your complete log slawek

Answer (score 0):

@Slawek Leh - hey when u get this kind of error that your are performing much work on main thread.

Two solution are :
1) use Asynctask for doing operations
2) or Add in your Code Above Acitivity:
`StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`

Answer (score 0):

Add simple one line code in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
< application
    android:allowBackup="true"

    android:largeHeap="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Apptheme" 
>
```